# Edit improves code without explanation

Tags: discussion, editing

I just rejected an edit on this answer:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/61524/262

The edit looks ok, but it changed apparently working code without explanation. The proposed edit is cleaner, and probably correct. But I was uncomfortable with it without the editor providing a cue to either the questioner or the answerer as to why they'd done it.

Not sure about this, maybe I should have accepted this one?

## Update

Here's another one:

[Default Inline Image Background in Org Mode](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20574/default-inline-image-background-in-org-mode/37927#37927)

It adds a customization variable to make the original answer more user-friendly. It doesn't really improve the answer, in terms of addressing the problem at hand, but it does make it 'better' in terms of the experience of users that add the code to their config.

Yay or nay?